# How to Ship Specific Logs with Nxlog to Logstash

Tags: logstash, nxlog

I am a sys admin intern and I'm setting up an Nxlog instance on a Windows Server 2012 VM that ships Windows Application logs and everything in C:\logs.  I already have the Application logs shipping just fine, but I cannot find a way to ship specific log files (such as C:\logs) for parsing.

This is what I have:

```
    Module      im_file
    File        "C:\logs\stuff.log"
    SavePos     TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to use TCP To move the files to Logstash, try this

```
<Input in>
    Module  im_file
    File    "c:\logs\stuff.log"
    SavePos TRUE
</Input>

<Output out>
    Module  om_tcp
    Host    192.168.1.1
    Port    514
</Output>

<Route 1>
    Path    in => out
</Route>
```

Comment: I have an csv file. How to make a log file of it? Which I then want to ship to logstash to visualize in kibana.